# How to interpret modularity of a weighted graph?

Tags: r, igraph

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_(networks)),

> Modularity is the fraction of the edges that fall within the given groups minus the expected fraction if edges were distributed at random

This definition is easy to understand for unweighted graphs, but several community detection algorithms that use modularity optimization, work for weighted graphs as well. All the community detection algorithms in `igraph` for instance, have a parameter to pass edge weights.

I'm trying to figure out how to interpret the communities for weighted networks in the light of modularity optimization.

Comment: From the title and from a quick look at the text, this seems like it would be a better fit for crossValidated or for math stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks, moved it to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734857/how-to-interpret-modularity-of-a-weighted-graph